# Invisible leading characters in URL

Tags: mysql, sql, url

I'm trying, using MySQL, to flag obvious non URLs among a column of what should be URL's.  I'm taking the first seven characters of the URL name and seeing if they come out to 'http://' or 'https:/'.  One URL, however, instead returns 'http:' like so:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(my_URL,1,7) FROM my_URL_table
```

Returns: `'http:'` - apparently five characters, not seven as expected. The offending, real life URL is:

http://www.wsmv.com/story/34609714/f...s-parade-crash

It's as if there were two extra characters, at the beginning of the URL, that are both invisible and take up no space.  (Dark matter characters?).  Indeed, if I run the INSTR function to see at which position `'http://'` starts in the URL, MySQL returns position 3, like so:

```
SELECT INSTR(my_URL,'http://') FROM my_URL_table
```

Returns: 3 and not the first position. I tried that SELECT with the addition of a `TRIM(my_URL)` function, but the TRIM changed nothing.

The URL was put into the table using an INSERT VALUES command that I wrote in Notepad++ and ran in phpMyAdmin.

Can anyone think what those mystery characters might be?  Advice on how to deal with them?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: fyi, the mysql: [HEX() returns a hexadecimal string representation of str where each byte of each character in str is converted to two hexadecimal digits](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_hex) which would be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know, but MySQL can tell you:

```
select ord(left(my_url, 1)), ord(substr(my_url, 2, 1))
. . .
```

The `ord()` function will tell you the numeric equivalent of the character, as explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_ord).

Comment: Thank you for that!  I ran the code that you suggested, to identify the characters involved, and got 13 for the first and 10 for the second.  If I'm right to think that those are ASCII characters, they are: 13 = carriage return and 10 = line feed.  I have to believe that I'm at fault for putting garbage in with the good as I populated my URL table.  I'll try to practice better hygiene and read up on how to find and remove those characters.  Would I have had that problem with a URLencoded URL?

Comment: Some more context: "Widely used formatting control codes include carriage return (CR), linefeed (LF), and horizontal tab (HT), which in ASCII occupy code positions 13, 10, and 9... . The "formatting" codes might be seen as a special case of device control, in a sense, but more naturally, a CR or a LF or a CR LF pair (to mention the most common conventions) when used in a text file simply indicates a new line." - from http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars.html#control

Comment: I went back to my code in Notepad++, and was able to "see" the offending carriage returns and line feeds after adjusting the View (View / Show Characters / Show All Characters).  I had included a set of CR and LF characters within the literal string used for the URL.  Notepad even colored the problem CR LF characters differently than the healthy ones.